# NAS Synology, use apache .htaccess for url-rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I try to making work a php site on my NAS Synolgy DS916Play.
The problem I have is I need to rewrite all api call to `index.php` with in form:

- Initial call: controller/action?queryParams  final call:
- api/index.php?*route*=controller/action&queryParams;

I try to put a `.htaccess` in site folder, but Apache didn't read this file (I put something wrong there, and no error occurred).

SO I need help in two problem:

1. Configure Apache on NAS, to read `.htaccess`,
2. A `.htaccess` file for what I need.

I have a version, but I'm not sure if it's correct:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^([\w\/\-]+)/?$ api/index.php?_route_=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Or if someone has other solution, I'm glad to hear it.
The site is One page application angularJS with backend php.

Comment: Have you ensured it is using Apache? According to Synology (https://www.synology.com/en-us/dsm/6.2/software_spec/dsm) it could also be using Nginx (as far as I understood)

Comment: You are right: I did installed Apache, but I forgot to change in Virtual Host config, the site backend from ngix in Apache. And now it work: Apache did read .htaccess, and the routing seem to be correct. I think you cand post as an aswer to vote-it :)